# is auto type detection only looking at one statement

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

For the two for loop below, are they equivalent? Basically does the auto look over "=0" assignment and see `iter` is compared with `s.size()` and so decides `iter` is of type `decltype(s.size())`?

```
string s;
for(auto iter=0; iter<s.size();iter++)

string s;
for(decltype(s.size()) iter=0; iter<s.size();iter++)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and see `iter` is compared with `s.size()` and so decides `iter` is of type `decltype(s.size())`?

No. [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) only deduces type from the initializer, given `auto iter=0;`, the type is deduced from `0` then it'll be `int`.

> in the type specifier of a variable: `auto x = expr;`. The type is deduced from the initializer.

And you can specify the type with `auto` like:

```
auto iter = 0u;  // unsigned int
auto iter = 0ul; // unsigned long int
auto iter = 0uz; // std::size_t, since C++23
```

BTW in `decltype(s.size()) iter=0;`, the type would be deduced from `s.size()` based on the rule of [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype), it won't be influenced by the fact that `iter` is compared with `s.size()` later either.

Comment: then for good practice, should i always decltype()? Any side effect of using auto (Since it is easier to type) in this scenario?

Comment: @WriteBackCMO you can't always `decltype`, suppose `auto i = 0;` is all you have, then `decltype(0) i = 0;` is a little silly ;)

Comment: @WriteBackCMO Yes you have to pay attention for it, if you don't want the type to be `int`. If you do know the exact type, you can write something like `auto iter = 0u;`, or `auto iter = 0ul;`, or `auto iter = 0uz; // std::size_t`.

Comment: @WriteBackCMO: Get rid of index, and go with for range: `for (auto c : s)` :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 will do. Going through some textbooks, so asking along the way.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Whenever a variable declaration has a "placeholder type" (`auto`, `decltype(auto)`, `const auto&`, etc.), only that variable's initializer is used to deduce the actual type.

So in the first snippet, the type of `iter` is `decltype(0)` is `int`.

Answer (score 3):

No, the loops are not equivalent.  `auto` deduces the type **only** from the initializer.  In your loop, that's `0` and `0` has the type `int`.  So your first loop is

```
for(int iter=0; iter<s.size();iter++)
```

while the second loop is

```
for(conatiner_size_type iter=0; iter<s.size();iter++)
```

where `conatiner_size_type` is most likely a `std::size_t`

---

Depending on what you are doing, you may want to use a ranged based for loop like

```
for(auto character : s)
    // loop logic
```

and this will loop through the string and `character` will be the character at the current position in the string the loop is at.